# Button on Annotation is not appearing

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I have a problem with my app. In fact, when I am running my code in a separate app it is working. xCode is not showing me any errors and everything works fine but I can't see a detail button in my Annotations on MapKit. Is there a problem deeper in xCode?

That is my code:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    let identifier = "Education"

    if annotation is Education {
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView!.canShowCallout = true

            let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
        } else {

            annotationView!.annotation = annotation
        }

        return annotationView
    }

    return nil
}
```

[It looks like this on my app - no detail button on the right side of annotation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZRvO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the delegate for your mapView. I usually do it in the viewDidLoad of the ViewController the mapView is in.

`mapView.delgate = self`

is the code you need to add.